# Unable to match image of same image size but shifted blob pattern

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, aforge, accord.net

I'm trying to match images with a template master image. The size of all images are same, but the blob pattern shifts within the image.

I tried thresholdfilter in aforge, it works great in finding the difference when blobs in defect sheets are aligned perfectly to the template image. If there is even a little variation all the blobs are detected as defect(different).

```
var img1 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(@"compare2.jpg");
var img2 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(@"compare1.jpg");

// (* calculate absolute difference *)
var difference = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ThresholdedDifference(15)
    {OverlayImage = img1}
    .Apply(img2);

// (* create and initialize the blob counter *)
var bc = new AForge.Imaging.BlobCounter();
bc.FilterBlobs = true;
bc.MinWidth = 5;
bc.MinHeight = 5;

 // (* find blobs *)
 bc.ProcessImage(difference);

 // (* draw result *)
 BitmapData data = img2.LockBits(
   new Rectangle(0, 0, img2.Width, img2.Height),
      ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, img2.PixelFormat);

 Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2); 

 foreach (var rc in bc.GetObjectsRectangles())
    AForge.Imaging.Drawing.Rectangle(data, rc, Color.Red);

  img2.UnlockBits(data);
   imageBox1.Image = img2;
```

Master Image:
[image: master template]

Shifted Blobs"
[image: Shifted Blobs]

How do I align the 2 images so that the pattern will always be perfectly aligned?

Comment: Find coordinates of the first blob in master image, then coordinates of the first blob in the second image and move the image so that those coordinates are the same.

Comment: Have you googled “image alignment”? There are soooo many different methods to do this!

Comment: @Andrey , i did find t he coordinate of the first blob in master and second image using the blob counter in aforge, But how do I move the image? Can you please share some code snippet or link.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the first blob on both images [you can use `CanvasMove`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/84bf0014-d288-bacf-bd47-64f223701130.htm) filter to align them perfectly:

```
// create filter
CanvasMove filter = new CanvasMove(new IntPoint(
    YOUR_X_DIFF, YOUR_Y_DIFF
), Color.Green );
// apply the filter
filter.ApplyInPlace( image );
```

You can also look into [MoveTowards](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f7f4ad2c-fb50-a76b-38fc-26355e0eafcf.htm) filter that tries to automatically align images (if I understood it correctly), description sounds like it might be useful:

> The result of this filter is an image, which is based on source image,
>   but updated in the way to decrease diffirence with overlay image -
>   source image is moved towards overlay image

Comment: @ Andrey ,This works great. I have one more question. Sometimes the object image is slightly warped due to bend in the object, this still causes false difference. Is there any way to check the difference between 2 images without them overlapping each other perfectly to get accurate results?

Comment: @Roshan not really. You need some logic that will anchor one image to another. A brute force approach would be to move one image over another pixel by pixel until the difference is minimal, this is what MoveTowards filter does (try using it). You can check its source code to see how they achieve it https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/a9453dad025d1fbffab165293cedc976187da535/Sources/Imaging/Filters/2%20Source%20filters/MoveTowards.cs

Comment: I tried Movetowards, it just creates a transparent overlay on source image. Doesn't actually moves the image.

Comment: @roshan as I said it might not be exactly what you need but if you look into the source code of MoveTowards it can give you an idea how to automatically anchor images onto each other.

Comment: @ Andrey, I found a mechanical way to align images. So that issue has been solved, Can you help me in grouping the blobs? In the above image there are 2 blobs in one set. How do I group them together (maybe a mask), so that in blob information I get the details of both like blob count.

Comment: @Roshan I think you have to implement the grouping logic yourself. Divinde blobs into two groups based on their size (large and small blobs). Then for every large blob look for a small blob that is 1) above it 2) closest to it.